# Migrating a SOAP App from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.0.2

Tags: magento2, soap

For Magento 1.9, I wrote an app that synchronizes selected columns from an MSSQL product database with the Magento MySQL database. The common key across the databases is a product sku.

This technique has worked great for years on Magento 1.9 and allows me to keep inventory in a brick & mortar warehouse sync'ed with the website.

The app uses a SOAP session to connect and exchange the product info ...

```
$soap = new SoapClient( 'http://www.mystore.com/api/?wsdl' ); 
$sessionId = $soap->login( $mage_user, $mage_api_key );

synchronize logic, etc.
```

I really don't need to re-invent this app, but I do need to connect it via magento2 SOAP.  I am struggling to understand how to do this, and googling just keeps taking me deeper into a black hole of confusion.

Has anyone experience of doing this?  Any templates?

Many thanks for any help / pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Magento2.0 is entirely revamp of the magento 1.x platform so your SOAP app won't work with Magento2 out of the box. I don't think there is any other way which shall migrate your soap client. You would need to amend changes on your soap client or better use the REST API for your client app.